# How to look through multiple arrays?

Tags: php

I have an array that looks like this?

```
Array ( [0] => 15 [id] => 15 ) 
Array ( [0] => 16 [id] => 16 )
```

I was wondering how can I know one from each other, if I want to echo the values separately?

```
$getid = mysql_query($query);
while ($get_id = mysql_fetch_array($getid)){
    print_r($get_id);
}
```

any ideas?

**edit**:

If I `echo $get_id['id'].', ';` I will get `15, 16`. What I want is to be able to echo them separately.

or the arrays to become:

```
Array ( [0] => 15 [id] => 15 ) 
Array ( [1] => 16 [id] => 16 )
```

**edit 1**: I figured it out:

```
 $i = 0;
 $getid = mysql_query($query);
 while ($get_id = mysql_fetch_array($getid)){
     $test[$i] = $get_id;
     $i++;
 }
```

Comment: what is your actual question?

Comment: well, if i 'echo $get_id['id'].', ';' i will get '15, 16'. what i want is to be able to echo them separately

Comment: What is the query that gets these values? Where does this data come from?

Comment: @Patrioticcow in that case you might want to read about First normal form, especially about Atomicity: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form#Atomicity

Comment: Please add you solution as an answer (and accept it). Editing the question to contain the solution is not helpful for this forum. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i figure it out

```
 $i = 0;
 $getid = mysql_query($query);
 while ($get_id = mysql_fetch_array($getid)){
    $test_time[$i] = $get_id;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need

```
$get_id['id']
```

or eventually

```
$get_id[0];
```